# Get the first previous element that matches a condition with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this table, how Can I get the first precessor that has the .cep class and get this element with Jquery??

This is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr class="cep"></tr>
    <tr class="ptype"></tr>
    <tr class="item"></tr>
    <tr class="cep"></tr> (I want to get this element)
    <tr class="ptype"></tr>
    <tr class="item"></tr>
    <tr class="item-here"></tr> (I'me here)
    <tr class="item"></tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
$('tr.item-here').prevUntilFindThefirstMatchOf('tr.cep'); Get this element
```

Help please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using [`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) in combination with `first`.  `prevAll` will filter all previous siblings by your selector and `first` just grabs the first one it comes across.

```
$('tr.item-here').prevAll('tr.cep').first();
```

```js
var meh = $('tr.item-here').prevAll('tr.cep').first();

console.log($(meh).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="cep"><td>This should not print in console</td></tr>
    <tr class="ptype"></tr>
    <tr class="item"></tr>
    <tr class="cep"><td>This should print in console</td></tr>
    <tr class="ptype"></tr>
    <tr class="item"></tr>
    <tr class="item-here"></tr>
    <tr class="item"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: and if there isn't any single match, it returns 0??

Comment: Yes.  prevAll filters.  If there are no matches the element list is 0 and can be determined as such by checking it against `.length` like any other jQuery object.  See my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvgps9f9/2/.  I moved the item-here to the top.  The console now does not print the text.  It prints a blank line because `.text` returns an empty string.  No elements were matched.

Comment: Working Like Charm Thanku :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [**prevUntil()**](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

```js
console.log($('tr.item-here').prevUntil('tr.cep').last().prev());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="cep">cep</tr>
    <tr class="ptype">ptype</tr>
    <tr class="item">item</tr>
    <tr class="cep">cep</tr> 
    <tr class="ptype">ptype</tr>
    <tr class="item">item</tr>
    <tr class="item-here">item-here</tr>
    <tr class="item">item</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add a .prev() to the end and this'l get the .cep el instead of all elements between here and .cep

Comment: @KevinB, I dont know, its getting both the last item before, and the item itself. I am surprised

Comment: that makes perfect sense if you think about it. The previous el of each of the selected elements was returned. so, adding a .last() before .prev() would fix that. `console.log($('tr.item-here').prevUntil('tr.cep').last().prev());`

Comment: But I want just the first match of tr.cep not all the elements until find this

Comment: @KevinB, you are awesome :)